# Scala Is it possible to run loops asynchronously?

Tags: scala, loops, asynchronous

I have a for loop that loops through a Iterable[String] and puts data into a mutabe.Map, is it possible to run everything in the iterable at once/amount at a time?

Comment: Do you want asynchronism or parallelism? How will you handle concurrent updates?

Comment: asynchronism and I dont now how to handle concurrent updates.

Comment: You could do `Future.traverse(theStrings){ aString => ... }` to run all of the calculations in parallel. That will return you a sequence with the results, and you can then add them all into your mutable Map (if that is really what you want to keep, in general, mixing mutable data structures with concurrency is asking for trouble) in one go.

Comment: Why do you want asynchronism? Do you want to the get a **Future** representing the process, or just fire it a forget? The solution to concurrent updates is synchronization; so, if the only thing you do during the loop is putting data into the mutable map, then doing the process asynchronously will only make the overall process slower, or do you do some heavy processing before adding the element into the map?

Comment: I was thinking of something like Python's concurrent Map method https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#Map.

Comment: That Python functions looks very similar to Future.traverse. And it has nothing to do with a Map datastructure, either. It maps a function over a number of input values.

Comment: Okay thanks, figured sequence works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use .par (converting collection to parallel) and then map/foreach over it.

Or you can map to Future.

Don't forget about thread safety of map - you should use ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: That works as well, thanks, but I have already mentioned that I am using `sequence` that works perfectly for what I am using.